# IPython Notebook internationalization

Tags: internationalization, ipython

I would like to translate IPython Notebook menu items and dashboard.

Which would be the best way to proceed?

Tnanks!

Comment: I'm curious about why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm planning to use IPython in an undergraduate class where some of the students don't know much English.

Comment: Come and talk to us on the [mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-dev). There was some discussion of internationalisation before, but it didn't go anywhere, and there's no machinery for that in place.